# Record and upload audio or voice in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to record voice and submit and store it in the server in my laravel project. I have been looking for it for a while yet couldn't come up with a proper method. Can anyone assist me?

I have only learnt about the audio tag where a source must be put. But I don't know how to put a recorded audio on a file in order to submit it in a form in my laravel project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use js library in client side for recording an audio. After that you should upload it with a simple html form into your laravel.

You can use this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API) for recording by javascript

and [this](https://laravel-news.com/uploading-files-laravel) tutorial for uploading form in laravel.

Comment: I figured it out. Anyway thanks for the response...